# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: butterknife.ButterKnife

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I've recently started doing Android development again and I am not yet used to the new gradle build system. Any dependency I add (so far I've tried Joda DateTime and butterknife), it always throws an error NoClassDefFoundError.

Here is what I've done. I'm using IntelliJ.

build.gradle:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.1'
```

File > Project Structure > Modules > MyModule > Dependencies > Add Library, download from Maven, click export and bump it up the list.

My dependency list now includes a maven module com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.1

What am I doing wrong here? My IDE resolves everything fine, but at runtime none of the classes can be resolved.

Side note: My BUILD would not even complete until I added the above line to build.gradle. So I have to add the dependencies in Project > Project Structure AND to the build.gradle?

Also my project structure is:

- UITest (parent)

  - UIBeta (android application)
  - UILib (android module)

I see the butterknife lib in the UITest\libs folder, shouldn't the children be able to find this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I was going to delete this but maybe it will help someone else:

My gradle clean was broken because some aar was locked and it could not delete it, I had to close out IntelliJ, rename the aar (appcompat7 I think it was), then restart. I might not even have had to rename the file as I'm guessing the lock was released upon closing.

After restarting my clean worked, upon next run no more error.